# Poisson Process Exercise

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-process

A flashlight needs two batteries to be operational. Consider such a flashlight along with a set of $n$ functional batteries — battery $1$, battery $2$, $\ldots$ , battery $n$. Initially, battery $1$ and $2$ are installed. Whenever a battery fails, it is immediately replaced by the lowest numbered functional battery that has not yet been put in use. Suppose that the lifetimes of the different batteries are independent exponential random variables each having rate $\mu$. At a random time, call it $T$, a battery will fail and our stockpile will be empty. At that moment exactly one of the batteries — which we call battery $X$ — will not have failed.

1. What is $\mathbb P(X=n)$?
2. What is $\mathbb P(X=1)$?
3. What is $\mathbb P(X=i)$?
4. Find $\mathbb E[T]$.
5. What is the distribution of $T$.

Comment: This seems like a nice problem, but I don't understand why one and not two batteries are left. We need three functional batteries to operate the flashlight, and then one fails, that leaves two, and from then on the flashlight is off, no? (Also, why did you introduce a symbol for $T$ but then didn't use it?)

Comment: Let's assume that it still works with one battery [this does not make sense practically, but that is what I really need to know]

Comment: But then there will be zero batteries left? Don't you need it to work with exactly two batteries?

Comment: You are right it makes sense, let's do 2 batteries then.

Comment: But actually, don't pay attention to the stockpile, let's say that we want to know probability that i is the last battery to remain alive.

Comment: But we do need to know how many batteries are in use at any given time. The edited question still says $3$, but in a comment you agreed that it should be $2$?

Comment: All I want to know that some battery i is the last to survive, that is it.

Comment: @joriki This is a problem from Sheldon Ross's *Introduction to Probability Models.* I've edited the question to include all parts of the problem (which resolves the mystery of $T$).

Answer (score 0):

For each $i$, take $X_i$ as the lifetime of battery $i$ and $t_i$ as the time battery $i$ is installed. Observe $t_1=t_2=0$.

Assume battery $n$ occupies the flashlight with battery $j$ for some $1\leq j \leq n-1$.

Knowing battery $j$ occupies the flashlight at the moment battery $n$ is installed tells us a critical piece of information: $X_j+t_j>t_n$.

Therefore,

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\mathbb{P}(X=n)&=&\mathbb{P}\left(X_n+t_n>X_j+t_j\Big|X_j+t_j>t_n\right)\end{eqnarray*}$$ The exponential distribution is *memoryless* which means $$X_j-(t_n-t_j)\big|\{X_j>t_n-t_j\} \sim \exp(\mu)$$ Because battery lives are independent among distinct batteries, the joint distribution of the random vector $\left(X_j-(t_n-t_j),X_n\right)|\{X_j>t_n-t_j\}$ namely $f_{X_j-(t_n-t_j),X_n|\{X_j>t_n-t_j\}}$ factors as $f_{X_j-(t_n-t_j)|\{X_j>t_n-t_j\}}\times f_{X_n}$. So, $$\begin{eqnarray*}\mathbb{P}(X=n)&=&\mathbb{P}\left(X_n>X_j-(t_n-t_j)\Big|X_j>t_n-t_j\right) \\ &=& \int_0^{\infty}\int_0^x\mu^2\exp\{-\mu(x+y)\}\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x \\ &=& \frac{1}{2}\end{eqnarray*}$$

This is your answer to 1. For question 2, notice that $X=1$ is equivalent to battery $1$ outliving all other $n-1$ batteries whose combined lifetime is $X_2 + \dots + X_n$ which possess an $\text{Erlang}\left(n-1,\mu\right)$ distribution. Since $X_1$ and $X_2+\dots +X_n$ are independent, $$\begin{eqnarray*}\mathbb{P}\left(X=1\right)&=& \mathbb{P}\left(X_1>X_2+\dots + X_n\right) \\ &=& \int_0^{\infty}\int_0^x \mu e^{-\mu x}\cdot \frac{\mu^{n-1} y^{n-2}e^{-\mu y}}{(n-2)!}\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x \\ &=& \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1} \end{eqnarray*}$$

Question 3 requires us to evaluate $\mathbb{P}(X=i)$ for each $i$. We already handled the cases when $i=1,n$ and from symmetry $\mathbb{P}(X=2)=\mathbb{P}(X=1)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}$. Now assume $3\leq i \leq n-1$.

$X=i$ says battery $i$ outlives all subsequent $n-i$ batteries as well as the other battery that already occupies the flashlight at time $t_i$. Suppose the other battery in the flashlight at time $t_i$ is battery $j$ where $1\leq j \leq i-1$.

Saying battery $j$ occupies the flashlight at time $t_i$ tells us $X_j+t_j>t_i$. Moreover, the time battery $j$ spends in the flashlight since battery $i$ has been installed is $X_j-(t_i-t_j)$. It follows that $$\begin{eqnarray*}\mathbb{P}\left(X=i\right) &=& \mathbb{P}\left(X_i>\left[X_j-(t_i-t_j)\right]+X_{i+1}+\dots + X_n\Big|X_j+t_j>t_i\right)\end{eqnarray*}$$ From memorylessness $X_j-(t_i-t_j)\Big|\{X_j>t_i-t_j\}\sim \exp(\mu)$ so with independence $$\left[X_j-(t_i-t_j)\right]+X_{i+1}+\dots + X_n\Big|\{X_j+t_j>t_i\}\sim \text{Erlang}(n-i+1,\mu)$$ We have $$\begin{eqnarray*}\mathbb{P}(X=i)&=&\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^x \mu e^{-\mu x}\cdot \frac{\mu^{n-i+1} y^{n-i}e^{-\mu y}}{(n-i)!}\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x \\ &=& \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-i+1}\end{eqnarray*}$$ We conclude that $\mathbb{P}(X=i)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}$ when $i=1$ and $\mathbb{P}(X=i)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-i+1}$ when $2\leq i \leq n$.

For the last two parts, take $T_{i+1}$ as the time in which battery $i+1$ is installed, where $i\in \{2,...,n-1\}$. Again assume battery $i$ is installed with battery $j\in \{1,...,i-1\}$

Then $T_{i+1}-t_i=\min\{X_i,X_j-(t_i-t_j)\}$ and so $T_{i+1}-t_i\Big|\{X_j>t_i-t_j\}\sim \exp(2\mu)$. Evidently $T$ is the arrival time of the $(n-1)^{\text{st}}$ arrival in a Poisson process with rate $2\mu$. The distribution of $T$ is known as $\text{Erlang}(n-1,2 \mu)$ which has expected value $\frac{n-1}{2\mu}$.